# SIMULINK :Frequency Multiplier

Tags: signal, signal-processing, matlab, simulink

I'm working on implementing Armstrong Modulator . I successfully implement the narrow band block but I'm struggling into finding a solution to multiply the frequency of my modulated signal .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Rayane, it is very difficult to give you any idea if you don't describe the problem in a way that enables us to understand what are your difficulties, what you already did and what you are trying to do. I'm struggling into find a solution to multiply the frequency" doesn't describe the problem in such way that someone could help. In the words that you described, the only thing that we could say is to ask you to search about Armstrong Modulator in textbooks and in Google. Please, edit your question adding more information, and if possible a schematic of your test circuit.

Comment: Do you have a schematic/block diagram of what you're doing?